# How to Stage/Commiting the current buffer in magit?

Tags: emacs, magit

I see several operations such as log and diff with the ***magit-xxx-buffer-file*** syntax which operate on the active buffer.

I am looking for the command which would stage or commit the buffer I am editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `magit-stage-file` is the command to stage the current buffer's file.

Or <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>M-g</kbd> for `magit-file-popup` and then <kbd>s</kbd>

Comment: Awesome, thank you! For those looking to stage only select hunks of a file: `C-c M-g` and `g` (for `status`). There, you can select individual hunks, and the current file is automatically selected. Thanks for the C-c M-g tip, @phils